# Unable to delete conditional formatting prior to adding new formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, gs-conditional-formatting

To ensure I don't keep adding the same rule over and over again, I try to first clear any conditional formatting on the column I'm working with (i.e. index 6). But when I do this, I keep getting the error:

```
Invalid requests[0].deleteConditionalFormatRule: No conditional format on sheet: [THE_SHEET_ID] at index: 6
```

saying that there is not conditional formatting on that sheet (which is incorrect).

The relevant snippet of my Apps Script code:

```
  ...
  var redWarning = Sheets.newRequest();
  var redWarningRequest = Sheets.newAddConditionalFormatRuleRequest();
  redWarningRequest.rule = redWarningRule;
  redWarningRequest.index = 6;
  redWarning.addConditionalFormatRule = redWarningRequest;

  var clearRedWarning = Sheets.newRequest();
  var clearRedWarningRequest = Sheets.newDeleteConditionalFormatRuleRequest();
  clearRedWarningRequest.sheetId = sheetID;
  clearRedWarningRequest.index = 6;
  clearRedWarning.deleteConditionalFormatRule = clearRedWarningRequest;

  // Batch send requests
  var requests = [clearRedWarning, redWarning];
  var batchUpdate = Sheets.newBatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
  batchUpdate.requests = requests;
  return Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate( batchUpdate, spreadsheetId );
```

If I don't include the `clearRedWarning` request, everything works fine, but this obviously doesn't clear the existing conditional formatting.

What am I missing here? Also, is there some way of only conditionally adding the format, i.e. only add it if it's not already there?

***EDIT**
As per request by tehhowch this is the JSON respons in the API explorer (with some values redacted):

```
{
 "sheets": [
  {
   "properties": {
    "sheetId": [REDACTED],
    "title": "[REDACTED]"
   },
   "conditionalFormats": [
    {
     "ranges": [
      {
       "sheetId": [REDACTED],
       "startRowIndex": 1,
       "endRowIndex": 1000,
       "startColumnIndex": 6,
       "endColumnIndex": 7
      }
     ],
     "booleanRule": {
      "condition": {
       "type": "TEXT_CONTAINS",
       "values": [
        {
         "userEnteredValue": "yes"
        }
       ]
      },
      "format": {
       "backgroundColor": {
        "red": 1,
        "green": 0.8,
        "blue": 0.8
       },
       "textFormat": {
        "foregroundColor": {
         "red": 1,
         "green": 0.2,
         "blue": 0.2
        },
        "bold": true
       }
      }
     }
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Regarding the JSON being sent... this is in Google Apps Script, so console log doesn't exist here. There is a "Logger", but not really sure what more you need from the request (it's in clear text above in "clearRedWarning" var (i.e. how the request is formulated).

Comment: Well, what does the appropriate [`spreadsheets.get`](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/sheets.spreadsheets.get?spreadsheetId=your+spreadsheet+id+here&fields=sheets(conditionalFormats%252Cproperties(sheetId%252Ctitle))&_h=2&) show for the file before you do this?

Comment: It shows the conditional formatting. Like I said, it's there... so I don't understand why the batch update says it's not? Also, will it throw this error if there isn't any formatting on that index? In that case, how would I do a conditional if statement that only applies the formatting if there isn't any?

Comment: [`console` sends the logs to Stackdriver. View -> Stackdriver logs.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#using_stackdriver_logging) SheetIds are unique to each `spreadsheetId`, so including the `sheetId` in the relevant JSON summaries will help us all determine if you are referencing the incorrect sheet in your deletion request.

Comment: Hmm, interesting @I'-'I That, at least removed there error  :) however, now there is no conditional formatting at all... How can I get the current conditional formatting in GAS of a specific sheet? With that I might be able to just do an IF statement and only apply it if necessary

Comment: @tehhowch I understand. However, the sheetId is passed as a variable to a function that does the conditional formatting, so there is no possible way it could be incorrect as it works fine with adding conditional formatting. The issue can't possible be with a sheed ID "typo". However, the index, pointed out by I'-'I might actually be something. I'll look in to that. Again, thank you all for your patients (and help!), GAS i new to me  : )

Comment: Yes, think I'm starting to get a handle on everything regarding this issue now (thanks to you guys!)... I think I can solve it from here... I'll post an answer when I'm done (for any other GAS noob getting stuck with this). Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> index
>
> > The zero-based index of the rule to be deleted.

It's NOT a column index. It's the index of the rule. `0` will be the  highest priority rule. `1` will be the next highest and so on. Your request for index `6` is valid, only if there are 7 conditional formatting rules present.

You can also try and issue both requests separately.  Regardless of whether the first request errors out(if there is no rule at `0`), you can issue the second request using `finally`.

#### References:

- [DeleteConditionalFormatRuleRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#DeleteConditionalFormatRuleRequest)
- [try..finally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)